# Slow subquery in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery

Having tried many different methods, I can't get my query taking shorter than 40 seconds to run with a dataset of ~11000 rows.

The table is a list of hotel bookings, containing (most relevant) Check-In date and Booking Value

My boss wanted a diagram where the values are summed for every month/year in a special way:

```
Row 1: Sum of value between Jan 2012 - Jan 2012
Row 2: Sum of value between Jan 2012 - Feb 2012
Row 3: Sum of value between Jan 2012 - Mar 2012
Row 4: Sum of value between Jan 2012 - Apr 2012
...
Row 5: Sum of value between Jan 2012 - Dec 2012
```

And so on for every year. Basically row 5 in this example would return the summed value for the entire year.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings` (
  `DBID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `checkin` date NOT NULL,
  `checkout` date NOT NULL,
  `total` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DBID`,`checkin`),
  KEY `total` (`total`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11171 ;
```

My query:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(checkin) as year,
    CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(MONTHNAME(checkin), 1)),SUBSTRING(MONTHNAME(checkin), 2)) as month,
    MONTH(checkin) as monthnum,
    (
        SELECT SUM(total)
        FROM bookings as book2
        WHERE YEAR(book2.checkin) = year AND MONTH(book2.checkin) <= monthnum
    ) as sum
FROM `bookings`
GROUP BY YEAR(checkin),MONTH(checkin)
ORDER BY YEAR(checkin) ASC, MONTH(checkin) ASC
```

So the subquery is the magic behind this query, it all produces the exact result I want, but the execution time is unacceptable.

I'm not sure how to optimise this further, I can't use joins since it's on the same table, I've indexed everything neccessary, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting the sub-query as a join:

```
SELECT YEAR(b1.checkin) as year
     , MONTH(b1.checkin) as monthnum,
     , SUM(b2.total)
FROM bookings as b1
JOIN bookings as b2
    ON YEAR(b2.checkin) = YEAR(b1.checkin) 
   AND MONTH(b2.checkin) <= MONTH(b1.monthnum)
GROUP BY YEAR(b1.checkin),MONTH(b1.checkin)
ORDER BY YEAR(b2.checkin) ASC, MONTH(b2.checkin) ASC
```

I also removed `CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(MONTHNAME(checkin), 1)),SUBSTRING(MONTHNAME(checkin), 2)) as month`, I don't think that will matter but it might be beneficial to do this once, and add it to the report in the application-layer.

You don't mention version of MySQL, but later versions have generated columns. You can try generating columns for YEAR and MONTH:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bookings 
( DBID int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, checkin date NOT NULL
, checkout date NOT NULL
, total int NOT NULL

, checkin_year SMALLINT as (YEAR(checkin))
, checkin_month SMALLINT as (MONTH(checkin)) 

,    PRIMARY KEY (DBID, checkin)
,    KEY total (total)

,    KEY (checkin_year, checkin_month)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11171 ;
```

and then use those columns in the query:

```
SELECT b1.checkin_year
     , b1.checkin_month,
     , SUM(b2.total)
FROM bookings as b1
JOIN bookings as b2
    ON b2.checkin_year = b1.checkin_year 
   AND b2.checkin_month <= b1.checkin_month
GROUP BY b1.checkin_year, b1.checkin_month
ORDER BY b1.checkin_year, b1.checkin_month
```

BTW, what is the purpose of the index on TOTAL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use join on the same table. Its called self join.

Like:

```
FROM `bookings` b 
INNER JOIN bookings book2 ON b.columnname = book2.columnname
```

Comment: Interesting, will this help me in my case though?

Answer (score 0):

If you had an indexed date dimension table, this would work much faster. They are quite useful for solving a number of reporting issues. A very simple example (your dimension can be as robust or simple as you require) would be:

```
CREATE TABLE month_dimension (Month INT, Year INT, First_Day DATE)

INSERT INTO month_dimension VALUES (1, 2015, '1/1/2015'), (2, 2015, '2/1/2015')...

SELECT a.year AS year,
       CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(MONTHNAME(a.First_Day), 1)),SUBSTRING(MONTHNAME(a.First_Day), 2)) AS month,
       a.month AS monthnum,
       SUM(b.total) AS sum
       FROM month_dimension a
       LEFT JOIN bookings b
                ON a.year = YEAR(b.checkin)
                AND a.month >= MONTH(b.checkin)
       GROUP BY a.year,
                b.month
       ORDER BY a.year,
                b.month
```

Comment: While it's significantly faster (17s) I can not get it to produce the results I want. I can't really explain what goes wrong but the value totals are several times larger than what they should be.

Comment: Are there unique entries in the month_dimension table for each relevant month at this point? The only thing I can think of that would cause the issue is duplicate month entries.

Comment: @Daniel is correct, the query will not produce correct results in the `SUM(total)`. Thomas, the table `booking` has of course multiple rows on the same year and month.